# count number that is not zero in data frame and get statistics on them

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that has a column that has lots of zeros and numbers. I want to create a histogram of the nymbers only and get statistics on them.
If I sum every thin it gives me all the values but I dont know the mean and std and so on. Also if I did describe. I t will count the zeros which I has a lot of them and Iam intrested only on numbers

```
data.values.sum()
data.describe() # counts also the zeros 
data.hist()# count zeros as well
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter for non zero values

```
mask = data['column'] != 0
data[mask].values.sum()
data[mask].describe() # counts also the zeros 
data[mask].hist()# count zeros as well
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of summing use method [.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```py
data.values.value_counts().hist()
```

Comment: This gives stats of the value count not the actual number. For example my numbers in decimials and it shos the mean is 10 which is not correct. I want to get the actual numbers only.